# Netbeans IDE Error: A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred

Tags: java, exception, netbeans-7

I have a exception when i use netbeans to open java project: 
A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred.
However, the system should continue working without further problems.
Click Show Details for the stack trace.

show detail:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.javaee.Hk2LibraryProvider
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.javaee.Hk2JavaEEPlatformImpl.(Hk2JavaEEPlatformImpl.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.javaee.Hk2JavaEEPlatformFactory.getJ2eePlatformImpl(Hk2JavaEEPlatformFactory.java:125)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.getJ2eePlatformImpl(ServerInstance.java:347)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.query.J2eePlatformSourceForBinaryQuery.findSourceRoots2(J2eePlatformSourceForBinaryQuery.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.queries.SourceForBinaryQuery.findSourceRoots2(SourceForBinaryQuery.java:126)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.PathRegistry.sourceForBinaryQuery(PathRegistry.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex.createQueriesForRoots(ClassIndex.java:658)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex.access$700(ClassIndex.java:100)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex$6.run(ClassIndex.java:620)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:367)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex.reset(ClassIndex.java:600)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex.(ClassIndex.java:299)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClassIndex.(ClassIndex.java:275)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ClasspathInfo.getClassIndex(ClasspathInfo.java:380)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.metadata.model.api.support.annotation.AnnotationModelHelper.registerPersistentObjectManager(AnnotationModelHelper.java:129)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.metadata.model.api.support.annotation.AnnotationModelHelper.createPersistentObjectManager(AnnotationModelHelper.java:121)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.impl.ejb.annotation.EnterpriseBeansImpl.initialize(EnterpriseBeansImpl.java:93)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.impl.ejb.annotation.EnterpriseBeansImpl.create(EnterpriseBeansImpl.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.impl.ejb.annotation.EjbJarImpl.(EjbJarImpl.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.impl.ejb.annotation.EjbJarMetadataModelImpl.(EjbJarMetadataModelImpl.java:88)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.spi.ejb.EjbJarMetadataModelFactory.createMetadataModel(EjbJarMetadataModelFactory.java:57)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.EjbJarProvider.getMetadataModel(EjbJarProvider.java:110)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.api.ejbjar.EjbJar.getMetadataModel(EjbJar.java:186)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.WebProject$ProjectOpenedHookImpl.projectOpened(WebProject.java:1021)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:85)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.UILookupMergerSupport$OpenHookImpl.projectOpened(UILookupMergerSupport.java:244)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:85)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(OpenProjectList.java:1218)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpenProject(OpenProjectList.java:1299)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.open(OpenProjectList.java:791)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$5.run(OpenProjectList.java:659)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
```

What is the problem with Netbeans and how can I resolve it ?

```
resolved: need to update IDE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, that situation was caused because of available updates for NetBeans IDE. Try to update IDE, restart NetBeans and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, it is because of  multiple times installation of

Netbeans. It installs multiple servers for example glass fish(in my

case), so delete the other unused servers. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may install font that does not support for your IDE. Please remove the font in your lib,and jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: solved by installing Java RE